# Problems with everything after update Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation

After update to version 12.04 the Update Manager crashes all time. In addition Firefox have lost most plugins, and its impossible install these it seems (no error, but plugins are still missing after installing). 
Even LibeOffice is changed. All icons are gone so its a text version now ("Summarize" in stead of icon for this "sigma-sy,bol").

Can I reset to older versions? Other suggestions?

In worst case I have to remove Linux and go back to Windows. :(

Comment: You Upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 from other versions or just did an update to already 12.04 version

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you download Ubuntu 12.04 from their [website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), put it on a cd, dvd, or usb, and do a clean install. It appears that you might have had a bad upgrade for what ever the reason. Hope this solves your question.